# Bounded modulo a constant

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

How do I put a tilde directly underneath an inequality (i.e. directly beneath < or >)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean `\lesssim` and `\gtrsim` from `mathabx` package?

Comment: I'm not sure what those are, but I think I mean something else

Comment: How about showing a screen shot what you are meaning, instead of letting us guess around? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
  The package \verb|amssymb| provides following:

  \verb|\lesssim| $\rightarrow \quad \lesssim$

  \verb|\gtrsim| $\rightarrow \quad \gtrsim$

  \verb|\lessapprox| $\rightarrow \quad \lessapprox$

  \verb|\gtrapprox| $\rightarrow \quad \gtrapprox$  
\end{document}
```

[image]